# What language should I use for this race-manager software?

Tags: software-development, database

I’m an intermediate programmer, I would want to create a software to manage a cycling race. Basically I have to deal with a database, (order partecipants, compile PDF files with rankings and so on…) but i’d rather not use Access… Any advice?

Comment: Is this question about a programming language or about a database? And frankly, for what you currently describe you can use almost anything. This question needs much more information to advise one over the other. Start with [edit]ing your question to answer my first question + is this online or local? + what budget do you have? + what OS?, then add more info

Answer (score 1):

[Python](https://www.python.org/) is probably the best <s>if you don't want to redistribute your program</s>. It's easy and quick to write and has tons of libraries.

[pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw) - a library for reading, morifying and writing PDFs
[sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) - simple sqlite library (included with python)

I think the simplest apporach to your problem is to create a sample PDF in some office program and use it as a base for creatnig leaderboards.

Then load the database in python and add the data into the PDF with pdfrw. If you run cycling races you could also store all of the data in one seperate database and render some statistic graphs with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and put them in your PDF or your website.

PyQt4 or tkinter are nice if you want some GUIs. I'd say to go with PyQt4.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was given a down vote, it covers the language, PDF and database requirements.  The only downside could be the "if you don't want to redistribute" part, as writing in Python wouldn't affect its ability to be redistributed

Comment: @gabe3886 Yeah, I don't know why I wrote that. Probably because of my experience with compiling PyQt4 and SIP.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) is an option to consider. Microsoft provides a free community version. You can write code in C#. There is a drag and drop designer included that makes it easy to build UI applications and also bind to data in databases. [Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229601(v=vs.110).aspx), [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt149845.aspx) and [UWP](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/windows-10-getting-started-with-uwp-14431) are options for desktop based UI platform.

[Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com) provides UI controls and file parsing libraries for all of the above platforms.

[Essential PDF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) can be used to generate PDF files.

[image: Visual Studio 2015]

The whole suite of controls and libraries is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue). Note: I work for Syncfusion.